# checking if the file upload is chosen or not in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form with input type file and its not compulsory to upload . But after the submit action occurs I want to check in the controller section if the file input is empty or not. I have a following view page and controller but the method is not working for me .

This is the form fillup page

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" 
  action="<?php echo site_url('welcome/do_upload');?>">
    username:<input type="text" name="username">
    <p>upload file</p>
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and this is the controller where am trying to check if the file is selected to upload or not .

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    echo( "image selected");
} else {
    echo("image not selected");
}
```

the output of the result is always the "image selected" though I don't select any image

Comment: debugging 101 - `print_r($_FILES['image']);`

Comment: Array ( [name] => rajeeb dupli.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpADA0.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 29139 )  yes the file is shown

Comment: how do i access those array value so that i can now check if name is not empty

Comment: just as you do for any other array.

Answer (score 1):

The error is when you submit the **FORM**

`$_FILES['image']` will always be created no matter what thus making your conditions true.

You are checking for the wrong conditions here, what you want to do is when a user uploads a file. You might want to do is to check if the `$_FILES['image']['name']` length is `> 0` or the `$_FILES['image']['size']` is `> 0`.

example, code not for production, just for testing.

```
if ( strlen($_FILES['image']['name']) > 0){
     //yeahhhh!
}
```